# HTML/CSS Place text over image without overflow?

Tags: html, css

I've placed some text on my website on top of an image, and it looks like this:

[image: Systems]

Now I want it to look like this:

[image: Systems fixed]

So, with the bottom half of the "y" cut off. My current html/css is:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header img {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #575757;
  box-shadow: 0.000em 0.188em 0.188em #999999;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.header span {
  font-size: 4.938em;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #999999;
  /*place it over heading image*/
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>Systems</span><!-- no whitespace
    --><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

How can I make it so any texts outside of the image cut off?

Comment: use overflow:hidden and give some fixed height to .header class. Then put height:100% to the image i.e. to .header img

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/107/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.header img {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #575757;
  box-shadow: 0.000em 0.188em 0.188em #999999;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.header span {
  font-size: 4.938em;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #999999;
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>Systems</span><!-- no whitespace
    --><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for one image. But I animate the "top" value of my span, so setting `bottom` to 4 doesn't work. However, by simply fixing the height of the text it looks like I'm getting somewhere :P

Comment: @TheOddler Yeah, and my point here were to use `position: absolute` to control the `span`'s position, overflow, etc., so it can be positioned over the image

Comment: What seems to work, and is very easy, is just fixing the height of my text to 0, leaving overflow to `visible`, and moving the shadow from the image to the header class. It's not really your answer, but it did get me there :D Should I accept yours or create an answer myself?

Comment: @TheOddler Its for you to decide, but normally an answer doesn't have to solve the question in an exact way, it can be enough showing how and then each user apply their extra customisation. I this case mine does fix the overflow you asked about but then needed an extra fix to make your animation work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden` to class `header`

Comment: I just tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/rj9utgv0/

Comment: you also have to set height for header class.

Comment: I got the problem, as your `position` property is creating problem

Comment: I have some javascript that alters the "top" css value of the text, so it does assume a certain structure. However I'm happy to check any suggestions, so go ahead and chage the structure, I can always update my js to make it work :P

Comment: check out this fiddle (It won't cut text but neither overflow) https://jsfiddle.net/rj9utgv0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need ? **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fL2dtc5g/)**

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header img {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #575757;
  box-shadow: 0.000em 0.188em 0.188em #999999;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.header span {
  font-size: 4.938em;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #999999;
  /*place it over heading image*/
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>Systems</span>
  <!-- no whitespace-->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, except the shadow is also gone, and my height can differ (I have multiple of these images with text on them at the bottom).

Comment: Hmm, almost-er. Only it should be cut off a little heigher. Not over the shadow. (I tried diabling the shadow but there is still that slight extra bit of white under the image then :( )

Answer (score -1):

```css
.header span

{

overflow:hidden;

}
```